# What is Analyze APK and its options in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am new in android. I want to know that the option Analyze Apk?

What is Raw File Size and Download Size means and other in this picture. Is this comparison need to be concern?
[image: This is my result]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html#view_file_and_size_information

Comment: here my raw size is 9.7 MB according to this when I install app in phone it'll take this much space. but my app is showing 14 MB while I install it.Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download size is the compressed size inside the apk package.

After your app installs on the device , it will take up the "raw file size".

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html

Comment: here my raw size is 9.7 MB according to this when I install app in phone it'll take this much space. but my app is showing 14 MB while I install it.Is there any problem?

Comment: Are you installing the app from the .apk itself or running trough Android Studio? It might be that Instant Run adds up some megabytes when debugging.

Comment: I disable my instant run.then generate apk and run it on my phone and the I get that result...

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the Math inside the APK Analyzer is wrong. Your res folder and class.dex obviously sum up to more than 10MB, so if you calculate all folders yourself , you'll get the real size.